# How to provide syntax highlight with antlrv3 generated lexer and parser?

Tags: java, parsing, syntax-highlighting, antlr3, rich-text-editor

How to provide syntax highlight with antlrv3 generated lexer and parser?
I want to develop an editor with the feature of syntax highlighting for learning purposes.However I am stuck with the Antlr generated lexer and parser.
I made use of the antlrv3 standalone editor.I integrated these with my Basic UI. However making use of this lexer and parser is proving to be a nightmare.
The generated lexer and parser for C language are generated in JAVA
Any suggestions?
Links for help?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you start following Sam Harwell's work on IDEs.

He builds then using ANTLR as a foundation, and seems to do pretty interesting stuff; not just highlighting, but also code completion and other more sophisticated tasks.

See his web page and research results at http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/research#section-1